# Algebra of Integrable Functions - Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

This is problem #22 from section 5.5 of Introduction to Analysis 5th edition, by Edward D. Gaughan.

Suppose $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$. Define $g_n(x)=f(x^n)$ for n = 1, 2, .... Prove that $\{\int\limits_0^1 g_n(x)dx\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ converges to $f(0)$.

Comment: What are your thoughts? Here's a hint: how would you prove it if $f$ were actually continuously differentiable? From there, use a density argument to finish the proof of the general case. Alternately you can use the Weierstrass approximation theorem to write a rather short proof.

Answer (score 1):

These functions are all uniformly bounded by $$M= \max_{0\le t \le 1}|f(x)|.$$  Also, save for at $x = 1$, they converge pointwise to $f(0)$ because $f$ is continuous.  What can you do with those two facts?

Comment: I have basically no thoughts. I'm completely lost.